# Удалить divider в меню NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, menu

Доброго всем времени суток. Подскажите, как удалить эту самую линию в списке меню? У меня в программе используется всего один пункт меню, остальные создаются программно. Я сумел скрыть линию, прописав в файле стилей это:

```
<item name="android:listDivider">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Но очевидно же что он просто стал прозрачным а не удалён. Стараюсь удалить:

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
menu.findItem(R.id.nav_auth).setVisible(false);
navigationView.invalidate();
```

[image: divider hide]

После запуска, пункт меню исчезает, но остаётся такое же пространоство, как показано на скриншоте между History и Settings. А если со стилей убрать строчку с `<item name="android:listDivider">@android:color/transparent</item>` и запустить, то видно что пункт меню исчез а линия осталась. Т.е. если даже вообще не подгружать список айтемов, запустить приложение и открыть меню, то всё что я увижу, так это только эту линию( Как удалить её подскажите?

Answer (score 0):

У меня в MainActivity был добавлен следующий код:

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
menu.addSubMenu(R.string.current_ads);
    navigationView.invalidate();
```

из-за него то и была вся проблема, а точнее из-за  невнимательности) Вопрос можно закрывать, проблема решена)